# How to transfer data from a document in CosmosDB to Azure SQL database?

Tags: json, azure, triggers, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to set up a system where my Azure function gets triggered (Cosmos DB Trigger) every time there is a new file in my Cosmos DB storage, and my goal is to get the incoming data from the file, and send it to my Azure SQL so I can make a live Power BI report based on that.
I have some questions about the whole process and I appreciate if anybody can help, because I am puzzled by the amount of information (relevant and irrelevant) I read on Microsoft Documentations.

1. Do I need to make a table in my Azure SQL database corresponding to the json data? Like do I have make the table template ready or the conversion happens automatically?
2. For such a scenario, when I make my Azure function, do I need input/output binding? My own understanding was that I wont be needing any binding but I am not sure.
3. Can I choose what data to be transferred to SQL from the document? Or I only can say that the whole data should be transferred to SQL database?
4. What is the command/code for such a task? for example if I want to say transfer these data (or the whole  document, giving it is a json file) to SQL database.
5. I didn't find any documentation for this specific task, so if any of you can send me a link to that, I would also appreciate.
6. To make the azure function to be sitting between Cosmos DB and Azure SQL database, I apparently need a collection/collection name to be included in my azure function set up, but I have no clue what that is, is it something to create when you create Cosmos DB on Azure?

I know this is too many questions, but I rather to ask them all at once instead of making several topics.
Maybe these information are already out there, but since I am new to this area and also coding, so I find myself getting lost pretty quickly, and I am not sure if I am looking at the right information/documentation/video tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the logic in putting the data in SQL? You can connect Power BI directly to Cosmos DB just fine.

Comment: The logic is that I am simply not allowed to have access to Cosmos DB database.

Comment: @SSRH Maybe you could adopt my idea.Any concern,please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you took to respond! In the scenario you described, what will be the role of the azure function? Also how does your scenario provide an advantage to the initial scenario? Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is detailed, I tried to cover all of your questions.

> 1.Do I need to make a table in my Azure SQL database corresponding to the json data? Like do I have make the table template ready or the
>   conversion happens automatically?

Yes ,you need to make a table which is corresponding to the json format in the cosmos db collection.It's does not happens automatically.

> 2.For such a scenario, when I make my Azure function, do I need input/output binding? My own understanding was that I wont be needing
>   any binding but I am not sure.

No,you do not need to configure input and output bindings.Just your cosmos db configuration is needed,such as db name,collection name.Please refer to this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger---c-example).

> 3.Can I choose what data to be transferred to SQL from the document? Or I only can say that the whole data should be transferred to SQL
>   database?

Until this question, I want to provide you with my suggestion based on your requirements.You could follow below steps:

a.Use Azure Function Cosmos Db Trigger to monitor the documents which is added or updated in your collection.

b.In above function,you need to collect the incoming documents then use cosmos db sdk to save them into a new collection.(call it temp collection now)

c.Here comes the point,use [Azure Data Factory copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) to copy data from temp collection into sql database.Please refer to these documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database

Back to the 3rd question, yes,you can.You could set [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db#azure-cosmos-db-as-source) settings to filter the source data.

> 4.What is the command/code for such a task? for example if I want to say transfer these data (or the whole document, giving it is a json
>   file) to SQL database.

Azure Data Factory copy activity could be called with sdk or powershell. Please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers).

> 5.I didn't find any documentation for this specific task, so if any of you can send me a link to that, I would also appreciate.

Find the answer in the above views.

> 6.To make the azure function to be sitting between Cosmos DB and Azure SQL database, I apparently need a collection/collection name to be
>   included in my azure function set up, but I have no clue what that is,
>   is it something to create when you create Cosmos DB on Azure?

To use my scenario,you need to create temp collection. After execution of copy activity,you need to empty it. I suggest you running the job daily so that you could empty yesterday data.